# Basic WebApp Questions

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications, vue.js

I am currently thinking about coding my first webapp.
I would say i have beginner to intermediate coding skills in html,css,js,jquery node,sql and monogodb.

The problem is that i do not really know how to achieve my goal.

My goal is to built a responsive single page website, which gets the stock price from an api and display it on one card. Furthermore the user should be able to click on the plus button and add another card with an stock index he chose from a choosing form option.

Now what want to know is:

1. Is this an example for choosing a js framework like react, vue etc. and how can I accomplish my goal ?
2. I coded the api get request etc. in node and was able to print everything I want into the console log. How do I do the same thing but displaying it on my html page ?
3. How can I create these cards which are automatically getting added to the homepage ?
4. How can I save the data for each individual card? (especially without a login procedure...)?

I know these are quite easy questions but I really want to learn how to do it.

Please check the images below.

(check: 
[image]
[image: The concept]

Comment: There are so many tutorials out there showing you how to do that. I still would use React over Vue because of ReactNative

Answer (score 0):

1. I would say try to use your existing skills to achieve your goals. When you run into problems you cannot solve or problems that could be solved by a specific framework such as react, try using them. It's better to understand what these frameworks are doing before you rely on them for every development.
2. You need to use an http framework like express to return your api values from node js to a web client.
3. Needs more info but as you're already talking about component based libraries, a good approach would be to keep the cards in a json array and render your page from that. If you are persisting the card data in a database you will also may want to render them server side as the page is loaded using a server side technology like node.
4. To keep things simple, you can store the info client side using something like localStorage or indexeddb. If you want to store something on the server side, you will need to introduce a way of identifying the user.